# Seeking online service to quickly review XYZ tiles

Tags: web-mapping, xyz-tiles, service-recommendations

I recently was approached by a layman who wanted to view a rather non-descriptive XYZ-tileset over a more relatable map like OSM. My first attempt would have been to create an html file from the openlayers examples hotlinking all the JS libraries. This turned out to be rather complicated since OL is deployed via npm. Same applies for the qgis2web plugin. Googling such a thing is very tedious as well so I ended up creating a QGIS project containing an OSM layer and said tile layer and sending the .qgz-file with something along the lines "install qgis and open this".

Is there such a thing like an online service that provides some basemaps with the ability to add layers and make that configuration shareable?

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the requirement here, but if it's just "something to allow easy viewing of an XYZ tileset hosted somewhere on the web" then the "sample_leaflet.html" that the [switch2osm guide](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-ubuntu-22-04-lts/) refers to might do the job (even local files).  After editing, it'll work with any data source that [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) understands.  There are lots of simple [examples](https://leafletjs.com/examples.html) on the main Leaflet site too.